# Incorrect vertical line spacing after changing font size in parcolumns

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing, parcolumns

Here's my test case...

```
\documentclass[english,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{
\tiny
\Blindtext[3][8]
}
\colchunk[2]{
\tiny
\Blindtext[3][8]
}
\end{parcolumns}

\Blindtext[5][8]

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following...

[image]

So my question is, *how can I fix the ugly large spacing in the `parcolumns` environment?* It appears to be trying to match the line spacing of the rest of the document and ignoring the change in font size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the spacing between lines for the whole `pacolumns` environment issuing

```
\linespread{0.75}\selectfont
```

just after the environment has started.

Note however that it is not possible to have different spacing for different `\colchunk`s.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\linespread{0.75}\selectfont
\colchunk[1]{
\tiny
\Blindtext[3][8]
}
\colchunk[2]{
\tiny
\Blindtext[3][8]
}
\end{parcolumns}

\Blindtext[5][8]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to place more `\colchunk`s with different font sizes, you can issue `\colplacechunks`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[english,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{
\Blindtext[2]
}
\colchunk[2]{
\Blindtext[2]
}
\colplacechunks
\linespread{0.75}\selectfont
\colchunk[1]{
\tiny
\Blindtext[3][8]
}
\colchunk[2]{
\tiny
\Blindtext[3][8]
}
\end{parcolumns}

\Blindtext[5][8]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It would be better, I think, to declare `\tiny` after starting the parcolumns environment, and do away with the `\linespread` stuff.

Comment: @jon I've tried it, but the result is ugly in that case, too.

Comment: I see.  I think the problem of ugliness is sort of endemic to the whole arrangement.  I meant it more with respect to the point about 'ignoring the change in font size'.  But I suppose you were thinking more about the 'ugly large spacing'.  Regardless, the OP should note that there are two different solutions to the problem.  (Not that this requires a separate answer.)

Comment: Thanks karlkoeller, looks a lot better now! I was doing exactly that - attempting to change the font size multiple times within the `\colchunk`. As a workaround I'll use two `parcolumns` environments one after the other. It'd be nice if I could stack `colchunk`s within the column.

Comment: @jozxyqk What do you mean with "stack `colchunk`s within the column?

Comment: Say I want the first paragraph in both columns to be regular font and the remainder `\tiny`. I can create two `\parcolumns` (the first regular and the second tiny), however the second set of columns will be aligned. If I could stack a regular and tiny `colchunk` in each column of the same `parcolumns` then I could finally have multiple font changes in each column.

Comment: @jozxyqk See if the edited answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Seems to be quite similar to multiple `parcolumns` - if one `colchunk` before the `colplacechunks` is longer it pushes both the `colchunk`s after it down - they align. This isn't an issue for me as my first columns are equal in length. I was just thinking about the next person with a similar problem. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @jozxyqk You're welcome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

What's going wrong? When you use `\colchunk`, the text is collected inside a box (a `\vbox`) which is then unboxed and this is where the problem appears: when the box is unboxed, the value of `\baselineskip` is not the one corresponding to `\tiny` any more, because `\tiny` was issued inside the box, so it vanished when the box was closed.

Solution: add `\tiny` outside `\colchunk`.

```
\documentclass[english,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\tiny
\colchunk[1]{%
  \Blindtext[3][8]%
}
\colchunk[2]{%
  \Blindtext[3][8]%
}
\end{parcolumns}

\Blindtext[5][8]

\end{document}
```

[image]